# How can i getText from li items, inside ol element with Nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I have to do a little test tool using NW to get titles to an array, from a simple ol li elements..Ex: i need an array with : Coffe,Tea, Milk.

```
<ol>
 <li>Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks for your cooperation in advance.

EDIT>>

Well, thanks to @SoftwareEngineer171 , I used .execute() to inject js to Nightwatch and is now running. This is the code i used and now working with array.. this code prints the number of li items of ol list (i used css selector anyway in this case) with @SoftwareEngineer171 code...

```
module.exports = {
'Demo' : function (client) {
client
  .url('http://mylink.com/items')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
  .execute(function(){
    var arr = (function(a, b){
        return (Array(a.length) + '').split(',').map(function(c, d){
            return a[d].innerHTML;
      });
      })(document.getElementsByClassName("listing-view")[0].getElementsByClassName("listing-view-item"));
    return arr;  
  }, ['arr'] ,function(result){
      array_h1 = result.value
      console.log(array_h1.length)
  })
  .pause(5000)
  .end();
  }
};
```

Comment: Pure Javascript- `document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');` If you want any more information I would like to see what you have tried yourself before I continue to help you.

Comment: Do you want pure JavaScript or selenium script??

Comment: Thank you people.. i have it resolved. I edited my post to show ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves your problem.

```
var arr = (function(a){
    return (Array(a.length) + '').split(',').map(function(c, d){
        return a[d].innerHTML;
    });
})(document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'));
```

**EDIT**

Ok, you requested explanation of this code, so here it is.
Firstly, we define `anonymous` function which requires one argument (this is the first function in the code) and we pass argument `document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].getElementsByTagName('li')` as variable `a` which represents all of your `<li>` elements. Now, `a` is an object which has `HTMLCollection` function as it's constructor, so it is not an array. To extract text from this collection, we must convert it to an array. This is the reason why we create new array and map each element from `HTMLCollection` to our new array. The second function you see simply copy each element from `HTMLCollection` object to array and then return array, as you wanted.
If it's still not clear to you what is `constructor`, `anonymous` function, array mapping, etc, I suggest you to read [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) article.

Comment: Thanks a lot SoftwareEngineer171 . Im totally newbie in this NW test tool, I use php-Laravel ,some C++ but nothing of javascript except some frontend snippets for charts, and some simple bots in NW etc.. Im trying to understand your code.. What a,b,c,d inputs are?

Comment: @Kalef. I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: thanks for you code! Now i m doing success tests with your help! I edited my post to show people how it has been implemented. Byby